# Svg height doesnt match with parent View height

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I have an Svg here with a Line. I gave Line stroke width as 10. The svg is wrapped in View with height same as stroke width 10. But somehow the Line doesn't align with the Parent height? What is causing the height difference?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {Svg, Line} from 'react-native-svg';

export default function App() {
  const width = 100;
  const height = 10;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ width, height, borderWidth: 1 }}>
        <Svg width={width} height={height}>
          <Line x1="0" y1="0" x2={width} y2="0" stroke="red" strokeWidth={height} />
        </Svg>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

expo link: https://snack.expo.dev/@lcherukuri/insane-yogurt

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a line? This should do what you want: <rect width={width} fill="red" height={height}/> or if you want you can also make it fill parent height with: strokeWidth="100%"

Answer (score 0):

The top of the line is getting cut off by the view because the line is placed centered along the top line. You will want to position the line in the middle of the viewport so that the entire line is visible. The position y1 and y2 are in the center axis of the line.

```
<Svg width={width} height={height}>
  <Line x1="0" y1={height/2} x2={width} y2={height/2} stroke="red" strokeWidth={height} />
</Svg>
```